# How to iterate through files in c?

Tags: c, file

I have to write a function that given two files, compares them both and writes on a third file each word they have in common, I tried with this one, actually making it write on terminal to see if it works, it actually iterates trough the second file but it only compares the first word of the first file, any suggestions?

```
void fileCopy(FILE *f1,FILE *f2){

    char fileString1[100], fileString2[100];
    
    while(!feof(f1)){

        fscanf(f1,"%s",fileString1);

        while(!feof(f2)){

            fscanf(f2,"%s",fileString2);

            if(!strcmp(fileString1,fileString2)) printf("%s ",fileString1); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) You could control the loops like this: `while(fscanf(f1, "%99s", fileString1) == 1)` and don't forget to `rewind(f2)` before the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

`while(!feof(f2))` loops until the end of the second file. You must iterate through both files simultaneously. Instead of these `while(!feof...` you should be checking the result of each `fscanf`.

A simple pseudo code example:

```
while(1)
{
  int fscanf1_result = fscanf(f1, ...);
  int fscanf2_result = fscanf(f2, ...);
  if(fscanf1_result != 1 || fscanf2_result != 1)
  {
    break;
  }
  /* rest of the code here */
};
```